# Как сделать сайт на AngularJS 1.5 + PHP доступным для поисковиков (Yandex, Google и тд)

Tags: php, angularjs, seo, индексация, продвижение

Создал сайт на angularjs, но столкнулся с проблемой индексации. Прочитал кучу инструкций, но не смог наиболее актуальный и не платный. Читал про prorender, но он платный при 250+ страницах. Кто то советовал использовать phantomjs + sitema, но как я понял он на nodejs

Есть ли какие нибудь проверенные способы открытия сайта на AngularJS 1.5 + PHP для поисковиков?

Comment: Что ж такого создают ангуляры/ноды что сайт невозможно индексировать? AJAX подгрузка контента без обновления страницы?

Comment: сайт на angularjs - это одностраничное приложение. Только на AngularJS 2 появилось генерить страницы для поисковиков

Comment: а URL'ы там существуют? В каком виде?

Comment: сайт на angularjs = это одностраничное приложение

Comment: главная страница заканчивается на /#!/ далее идет название страницы
http://site.ru/#!/page

Comment: Гугл же вроде умеет индексировать адреса после #!

Comment: а Yandex научился?

Comment: Честно, не знаю, лучше у него у самого спросить))